# Can I say "copied-and-pasted"?

Tags: word-usage

As far as I understand *copy-and-paste* is used to mean the operation of copying, and pasting.
If somebody did that, can I say (for example) the following?

> She copied-and-pasted what I wrote on my blog, changed some words, re-ordered some phrases, and then published that on her own blog.

Comment: I think both this use and that put forward by @EricS are acceptable; and EricS' version falls better on the ear.

Comment: @StoneyB I agree that both are acceptable, except that if I wrote "She copied and pasted", I wouldn't use hyphens.

Comment: @snailplane I wouldn't either; but I wouldn't throw a hissy fit if somebody else did. :)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51966/is-there-a-single-word-for-copied-pasted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Copied-and-pasted" would be totally understandable, but more often I hear "copy-pasted."  This stems from the fact that most people seem to say "copy-paste" rather than "copy-and-paste" nowadays.  So yes, your sentence makes sense and is correct, but more common would be these:

> We don't have time to retype it, just **copy-paste** it and let's go!
>
> I didn't want to type the whole page by hand, so I found the book online and **copy-pasted** the relevant section.

Comment: I've never thought about this before.  Is this the birth of a new verb, "to copy paste"?  I see it written "copy paste", "copy-paste", "copy/paste", and "copypaste".

Comment: @snailplane Indeed!  I usually use it in speaking rather than written language, but it could be written in any of those ways.  (In my head I think it as "copy/paste", though I don't know if it counts as a word when it has a '/'? ;)).  But yes, I say this quite often and have heard it from others as well, so I think it is becoming quite common!

Comment: Lets not forget "copypasta", the stuff that was copied.

Comment: @Ryan Oh, good point! But just to be clear (for the sake of ELLs), "copypasta" is generally considered slang, not Standard English.

Answer (score 3):

It's much more common to hear:

> She **copy-and-pasted** what I wrote...

Answer (score 1):

"Copied-and-pasted" would be the adjective form. "Copied and pasted" is a phrase containing two past-tense verbs.

"She copied and pasted a copied-and-pasted comment."

Comment: What are you basing this on?

Answer (score 0):

I think we don't even need to mention "paste'. If we use the word "copy" only then it will also mean as copy-paste. e.g. If I am reading a blog in which blogger has used the content from my blog then I can comment as "Mr. ABC has copied the content of by blog". It means that Mr. ABC has copied from my blog and pasted for his usage.

This comment is based on my own understanding, if am mistaken then please rectify.

Comment: While it is true that it is often unnecessary to mention the *paste* part of the action, it is common practice.  Especially if the copy is purely verbatim.